# SQL - Oracle 11g - Why get "missing right parenthesis" error?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is my SQL query on **Oracle 11g (sql developer)**: *(I copied it exactly from the book: "Fundamentals of Database Systems", 6th edition)*

```
select fname, lname
from employee
where NOT EXISTS ( ( select pnumber 
                  from PROJECT 
                  where dnum=5 )
                  except (select pno 
                          from works_on 
                          where ssn=essn ) );
```

It returns this error:

```
Error at Command Line:6 Column:18
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
```

I dont know how to fix this error yet.. cause for what I see my parentheses are balanced. Hope you guys could help me with this, i'm very appreciated.

Comment: There is no EXCEPT clause in Oracle SQL.

Comment: However, there is a minus clause that does exactly the same thing.

Comment: i changed to MINUS clause but the same error appear :(

Comment: @rainman_TS7 - your code is valid if you just replace the word `except` with `minus`, so maybe you deleted a `)` while adjusting it?

Comment: thanks @AlexPoole, i got my error fixed !